# How to access the RichEditBox control from within the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

So I'm just trying to figure out how to access the RichEditBox control from within the View Model of my app. Is this at all possible without using an anti-pattern?

The only way I know to gain access to the control in my View Model is to pass it to a property within the View Model instance. For example:

```
public MainView()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    // Instantiate the ViewModel:
    MyViewModel vm = new MainViewModel();
    {
        myRichEditBox = this.richEditBoxElement;
    }
}
```

So now the MainViewModel instance (vm) contains a field called myRichEditBox that points to the RichEditBox I am trying to manipulate from within the View Model. Is this an appropriate way of accessing it or is it an anti-pattern? Is there a better way to access it?

Comment: You should not have to have access to UI elements from the viewmodel. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well if I was using a TextBox this would not be a problem but the RichEditBox REQUIRES manipulation via C# code.I'm am trying to write data from my database to and from this control.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to access the text that the user types into my RichEditBox. And I'd also like to be able to insert text from my database into the RichEditBox as well. What is the best way to go about doing this while using the MVVM pattern?

Comment: The ViewModel is called ViewModel for a reason - you shouldn't have references to screen elements.  _"RichEditBox REQUIRES manipulation via C# code"_ - instead you may want to do that from the View's _code-behind_ (xxx.xaml.cs) file.  I ran into a similar thing with `PasswordBox`

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Actually, all of these comments TOGETHER helped paint a better picture of what the control is all about but I found a work around that will work well in my particular case. :]

Answer (score 0):

The out of the box RichEditBox isn't made for databinding :( however you should never expose the controls from the view towards the viewmodel because that goes against everything MVVM stands for.

there are some solutions of people who created Bindable RichEditBoxes. you could give this a try:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66054/A-Bindable-WPF-RichTextBox (haven't tried the example myself)

Comment: Thanks. I think for now I'll go with the Textbox. It actually will work for what I need to do AT THE MOMENT. I now understand what the RichEditBox was actually designed to do.

Comment: However, I will say that the UWP libraries available so far are quite primitive in comparison to what is allowed with the WPF-specific libraries. I could see why many developers aren't rushing to adopt it. SMH...